# Ocaml String.sub: How to get all characters until end of string

Tags: string, ocaml

So I'm using the String.sub function and I'm wondering if there's any way to get all the characters in a string until the end of the string. Since String.sub takes in a string, int (the index of where to start getting chars), and then a number of how many chars, I'm not sure what the easiest way of doing all chars since we want a possibly positive infinite amount

Comment: Unless I've misread the question, this should be trivial. Have you tried anything yourself? Is there something specific you're struggling with? You are generally expected to make an effort yourself before asking here, and to demonstrate that you have done so in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For `String.sub` you just have to subtract from the length of the string. There's no simpler way, i.e., there's no value for length that has a special meaning. A value larger than the remainder of the string is an error in OCaml (which tends to be strict when checking parameters).

Assume i is >= 0 and < length of the string:

```
String.sub s i (String.length s - i)
```

You can use `Str.last_chars`, but you still need to know how many characters you want. I.e., you still have to subtract from the length of the string.

```
Str.last_chars s (String.length s - i)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is *possible* to do without calculating the length of the string. If we convert to a sequence, we can then drop the initial number of characters up to the start index, then convert the remainder back to a string.

```
# let from_idx_to_end s i =
    s 
    |> String.to_seq 
    |> Seq.drop i 
    |> String.of_seq;;
val from_idx_to_end : string -> int -> string = <fun>
# from_idx_to_end "hello" 2;;
- : string = "llo"
```

However, this is shown merely for demonstration. The approach using `String.length` and `String.sub` is preferable for actual use.